# Using generic parameter vs. object

Tags: c#, .net

I have this extension method:

```
public static SqlParameter SqlParam(this object value, string parameterName)
{            
  SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(parameterName, value == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : value);
  return param;
}
```

From looking at some other examples, I also noticed, Another option is to declare the method as:

```
public static SqlParameter SqlParam<T>(this T value, string parameterName)
```

Usage is the same:

```
myValue.SqlParam("@myParam")
```

since I'm new to C#/generics, Now I wonder which is better approach and what is the difference between the two in terms of concept, except for the obvious (generic/object). Which one should I prefer and why, what are the advantages/cons between the two method is this situation?

Comment: I think in this case, both are work same but if you make this more generic, means that it return object in case of parameter is object and return type T when it takes parameter T. Then you can find generic is doing better work than object one. because at time of returning value you don't need to unboxing.

Comment: Your method *does* involve casting anything to object, even though it isn't. It forces boxing value types like ints, floats etc into objects, so it's slower. It loses type information. Actually, why don't you just use `Parameters.AddWithValue` ? I'm not sure you need to use DBNull.Value either, but even if you did, you could just write `value ?? DBNull.Value`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @ZoharPeled which is exactly what the OP is trying to do here. The very same problem, the very same drawbacks. The question is already closed as a different duplicate though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree. @zig: In this case there is no advantage to using generics, since the `Value` property of SqlParameter is of type `object` - therefor you can't avoid upcasting / boxing anyway.

Comment: @ZoharPeled actually, there is no advantage to this method at all, but there *is* another ugly smell - why create a *new* parameter for every object? The sproc or query doesn't change, so there is no need for new SqlParameter instances. The OP should set the value of the original parameters. Creating a new SqlParameter for each value just wastes CPU and RAM

Comment: @zig a SqlParameter object represents a query's or stored procedure's  *parameter*, not the parameter's value. Creating a new one for each value is simply wasteful. Create your SqlCommand and set its parameters *once* then change their values each time you want to call it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Also, the name of the method should be `GenerateSqlParameter`, and it should accept another argument - `SqlDbType`. I can see a lot of other things we can talk about on this code, but I think it's kind of a waste of our time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `value ?? DBNull.Value` gives me `Error 2 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'System.DBNull'` in the generics method, but compiles fine with the object parameter.

Comment: @zig Just *don't* use this method, create proper parameters *once*, with the appropriate types *and sizes* and set their values each time you need them. What's the point of recreating a parameter for each value? What you are trying to do here is identical to the existing `AddParameterWithValue` method, which isn't considered a good idea. Zohar already posted a link that explains [why](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, The `SqlDbType` is not needed in all the cases I checked. the framework knows to map the db type. in case I actually need `SqlDbType` I can write an overload method.

Comment: @zig you are wrong. It *is* needed because the framework *doesn't* know how to map to the correct db type. The types *don't* match, eg DateTime and `date`, or `String` and `varchar`, or `String` and any fixed-length string like `nchar(3)`. That's exactly why the identical, existing `Parameters.AddWithValue` is considered a bad idea

Comment: @zig - http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, This method is called in a web service for each request. where a new connection/command is initiated. I can't understand how to implement what you suggest. I think the `new SqlParameter` overhead is neglect-able in my case. But again I might be wrong.

Comment: @zig what's wrong with `Parameters.Add` when you create your *SqlCommand* object? What do you want the value for? Web service or not, you can create the SqlCommand *once*, store it in  a field and reuse it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks. I see your point about reusing  SqlCommand, but then I will need to create a *static*  SqlCommand in my web service. no?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavo, regarding the type mapping, in all the SP I used the mapping was *correct*. only when I needed to use TVP I needed to specify the `SqlDbType`. I don't mind the framework passing `nvarchar(3)` (`String` with length of 3) parameter for a SP expecting `nvarchar(MAX)`, and as I said if I do *need* a specify the exact `SqlDbType` I already nave an overload method. I pretty sure the mapping is accurate in most cases.

Comment: @zig read the article. You *do* mind, a lot, if that prevents the optimizer from using an index. The mapping isn't accurate. And code that duplicates existing behaviour is just wasteful

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'll read it now. why does `value ?? DBNull.Value` produces the error `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'System.DBNull` for the generics variant?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I needed to case it as `(object)value ?? DBNull.Value`. so we use an object cast once again... :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Thanks for the article. it was very usfull.